# Display every upcoming privilege instead of just one of them on the privileges page

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, privileges-page

This may seem trivial, but it appears on all SE sites, and possibly affect many users.

Page in question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

When the next privilege level has two privileges, the progress bar on the right only displays one. This is at **10, 15, 100, 500,** and **1000** rep.

**Privilege List:**

[image]

**Progress bar only displays one:**

[image]

Comment: And before someone gives us a reason to bludgeon them with giant letters, if this is implemented and it displays both privileges, please pluralize the text above it.

Comment: @all Thanks for voting this question up to allow me to achieve above-mentioned privileges.

Comment: reduce ADs? There are no ads on meta?

Comment: @JanDvorak good spot! (I didn't notice this as I'm using an ad blocker)

Comment: @SamuelLiew I have specifically disabled adblock across the stack overflow network. So far, zero clicks for me (discounting intra-se ads)